# button click event is triggered after keypress using jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, keypress

I have these codes

```
$('#search-button').keypress(function (e) {
   if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {            
        search();
   };
});

$('#search-button').bind('click', function () {
   search();
});
```

under the search module I have an alert, now whenever I press Enter when the button is in focus, the search() under the click event also triggers. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: it makes two call of `search()` ?

Answer (score 6):

Pressing enter does fire the keypress event - but also triggers the button's 'click' event, so you get search called twice.

You don't need to add a handler for the enter key.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
$('form').bind('keypress', function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13)
    {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#submitcat").click();
    }
});
$("#submitcat").click(function(){
alert("Ok");    
});
});
```

Comment: Just dumping some (badly indented) code is not answering the question. Please edit to add a real answer and please fix the code layout.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put the `keypress` event on the button? Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on it will trigger the `click` event anyway. You'll probably want to put the `keypress` event on the text input or drop it altogether.

Comment: One reason I had to do so, was because of Accessibility standards requiring keyboard only navigation. With Chrome and Firefox, the Enter key registers as `click`. But IE it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keypress',function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
        var identifier = e.target.id;
        console.log(e.target.id);
        $('#' + identifier).click();
    }
});
```