# I want to add keyup and click on a button

Tags: javascript

whenever the user press or click the button with the #btnsubmit the ajax executes. but when i press enter. both keyup and click executes.
but when i use click. it only executes the click function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function loaddelegates($barcode)
         {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("getdel").innerHTML = this.responseText;
               $("#btnsubmit").focus();
              }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "activityclient/" + $barcode, true);
            xhttp.send();
          }

       function storetime($barcode)
         {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("getdel").innerHTML = this.responseText;
               $("#barcode").focus().select();
              }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "activityclient/" + $barcode + "/store", true);
            xhttp.send();
          }

   $(function() {

         $(document).on('keyup','#barcode',function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
              if (code == 13 && $(this).val().length >= 1) {
                  loaddelegates($(this).val());
                  return false;
              }
        });

              $(document).on('keyup','#btnsubmit',function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
              if (code == 13) {
                 var barcode = document.getElementById('barcode').value;
                  storetime(barcode);
                  return false;
              }
        });

         $(document).on('click','#btnsubmit',function() {
                 var barcode = document.getElementById('barcode').value;
                  storetime(barcode);
                  return false;
        });
      });
```

thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, you want pressing enter to fire event X once and clicking the same button to fire event X once?

Comment: yes. so the user just have to choose what he wants to use either click or pressing enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add an event handler for the enter key. Remove it and that should work.

[button click event is triggered after keypress using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447050/button-click-event-is-triggered-after-keypress-using-jquery)